How do I handle a function that is calling a repository and also being used in two separate ViewModels
I have two ViewModels that contain the same function. The function calls an interface/repository to retrieve data from a database, and the function then manipulates the data.
It is my understanding that the repository should only handle the call to the database and the ViewModels should never interact with each other. I also do not want this function residing in both ViewModels since that would have an unnecessary additional call to the database and it just seems to be redundant code to me.
Therefore, what is the best practice to have this function only written once and be accessible to both ViewModels?
Repository:
class PartsScreenImpl : PartsScreenRepository {
    private val log = logging("KMLogging Tag")
    private val db = Firebase.firestore
    private val storage = Firebase.storage

    override suspend fun getPartsList(): QuerySnapshot {
        val result = db.collection("parts").get()
        val doc = result.documents
        return result
    }
}

Function in question
private fun getPartsList(): List<Part>? {
    val result = runBlocking {
        val querySnapshot = async {
            return@async repository.getPartsList()
        }.await()
        return@runBlocking querySnapshot
    }

    val documents = result.documents

    var partsList: MutableList<Part>? = null

    for (document in documents) {
        val partNumber = document.get<String>("part_number")
        val partDesc = document.get<String>("part_desc")

        val partImage = getImageUrl(partNumber)

        val part = Part(partNumber, partDesc, partImage)

        if (partsList == null) {
            partsList = mutableListOf(part)
        } else {
            partsList.add(part)
        }
    }
    return partsList
}

Code that calls the function
fun getOrderSummary(order: List<OrderReportData>) : List<OrderPart> {
    val partsList = getPartsList()

    val orderSummary = mutableListOf<OrderPart>()

    for (part in partsList!!) {

        val orderCount = order.filter { it.orderPart.number == part.number }


        var orderPartQuantityList: List<Double> = emptyList()

        try {
            orderPartQuantityList = orderCount.map { it.orderPart.qty.toDouble() }

        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            Log.e("mytags", "Invalid number format", e)
        }

        val partQuantityDouble = (orderPartQuantityList.sum())

        val partQuantity = if (partQuantityDouble.rem(1).equals(0.0)) {
            partQuantityDouble.toInt()
            } else {
                partQuantityDouble.toBigDecimal().setScale(1, RoundingMode.FLOOR).toDouble()
        }

        val orderPart = OrderPart(part.number, part.desc, partQuantity.toString())

        if (orderPart.qty.toFloat() > 0) {
            orderSummary += orderPart
        }
    }
    return orderSummary
}


I think what you're looking for is the Domain Layer
From the first snippet:

The domain layer is responsible for encapsulating complex business logic, or simple business logic that is reused by multiple ViewModels. This layer is optional because not all apps will have these requirements. You should only use it when needed-for example, to handle complexity or favor reusability.

Edit:
For example (I don't have an IDE currently and i'm not sure if you can return an optional) :
class PartListUseCase(repository: PartsScreenRepository) {

    operator fun invoke() : List<Part>? {
        return getPartsList()
    }

    private fun getPartsList() : List<Part>? {
        val result = runBlocking {
            val querySnapshot = async {
                return@async repository.getPartsList()
            }.await()
            return@runBlocking querySnapshot
        }

        val documents = result.documents

        var partsList: MutableList<Part>? = null

        for (document in documents) {
            val partNumber = document.get<String>("part_number")
            val partDesc = document.get<String>("part_desc")

            val partImage = getImageUrl(partNumber)

            val part = Part(partNumber, partDesc, partImage)

            if (partsList == null) {
                partsList = mutableListOf(part)
            } else {
                partsList.add(part)
            }
        }
        return partsList
    }

}


Thank you. That makes a lot of sense. I struggled to understand the concept of the domain layer, and your answer summed it up perfectly.

The simplest solution is to extract the logic into a separate function (a more sophisticated way would be to apply the Use Case Pattern which I will not further elaborate in this answer).
But before continuing, let's first simplify your view model's getPartsList. There is a lot of unnecessary code that can be written much more concise. The entire function can be reduced to this:
private suspend fun getPartsList(): List<Part> =
    repository.getPartsList().documents.map { document ->
        Part(
            number = document.get<String>("part_number"),
            description = document.get<String>("part_desc"),
            image = getImageUrl(document.get<String>("part_number")),
        )
    }


This assumes Part to be declared like this:
data class Part(
    val number: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val image: Any?,
)

Please adapt as needed. Make sure, though, that it is a data class and that all properties are val, not var.

The return value cannot be null anymore. A function that returns a List should return an empty list when there are no elements, not null.

The function is now a suspend function. You should never use runBlocking in an Android app, that defeats the whole purpose of suspend functions and will make your app unresponsive, maybe even get it killed by the Android system (ANR). Instead you need to launch a coroutine to call suspend functions. That is easy in a view model, you can use viewModelScope.launch { getPartsList() } for that. But there is even a better way, we'll come back to this later.


For now, the main issue is still that the mapping code (creating a Part from a Document) needs to be duplicated for each view model where it is needed.
The solution is to extract it to a new constructor-like function (a function that looks like a constructor when called but is just a simple function returning a Part):
fun Part(document: DocumentSnapshot): Part = Part(
    number = document.get<String>("part_number"),
    description = document.get<String>("part_desc"),
    image = getImageUrl(document.get<String>("part_number")),
)

Place it on the top-level of a file of your choosing where both view models can access it. Then the view model function can just call it like map { document -> Part(document) }. Since the mapping block now consists only of calling this new function we can convert the verbose lambda usage to the much more compact function reference syntax:
private suspend fun getPartsList(): List<Part> =
    repository.getPartsList().documents.map(::Part)

That's it. Both view models can now access the same logic whithout duplicating it.

What remains is how getPartsList() should be called, now that it is a suspend function.
You didn't provide any more code, especially not how you use this function. Since it is private it seems it is used only internally as part of some other processing. The main issue is that the returned List can change over time. You would need to execute this function over and over, whenever anything is changed in the Firestore. Moreover, you might not even know when you need to call this function, because the cloud storage could be changed from another device.
The solution for that is to let the Firestore notify you when a new value is available. That sounds complicated, but Kotlin provides a powerful yet very simple-to-use API for that: Flows. Luckily the Firestore already supports flows out-of-the-box. Therefore, you can refactor your repository function to this:
override fun getPartsList(): Flow<QuerySnapshot> =
    db.collection("parts").snapshots()

A Flow is a container of a value that can change over time. The flow will automatically provide a new value in that case, you do not have to poll for new values or register a listener or anything similar. The only thing to do is to collect the flow. You will do that at the latest possible moment, usually that will be in the UI. Until the flow reaches the UI you will only transform the flow or simply pass it through.
Your repository retrieves the Firestore flow of "parts" and passes it to the view model. The view model then only needs to transform the flow. Since flows are usually obtained outside of a coroutine you don't need suspend functions any more:
private val partsList: Flow<List<Part>> =
    repository.getPartsList().map { it.map(::Part) }

Actually, you do not even need a function in the view model at all: partsList is now a property that contains a List wrapped in a Flow. As you can see, the repository's  Flow<QuerySnapshot> is transformed into a Flow<List<Part>> by using the Flow's map function. Whenever the flow emits a new value, it.map(::Part) is executed again. You can now use this flow however you like to compute your final UI state that is then exposed to the UI. Just make sure to use flow functions like map, flatMap, combine and so on to further process the flow's value.
Since you didn't provide what you want to do with the list of parts, for the purpose of this answer let's assume you simply want to pass that list to the UI to display it.
For that you need to convert the flow into a StateFlow (that is a specially configured flow that always has a value and that can be observed for changes) like this:
val uiState: StateFlow<List<Part>> =
    repository.getPartsList()
        .map { it.map(::Part) }
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5.seconds),
            initialValue = emptyList(),
        )

Then, in your composable (I assume you use Compose since you tagged the question with android-jetpack-compose) you can convert the Kotlin StateFlow into a Compose State:
val parts: List<Part> by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

You need the gradle dependency androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose for that. This example also uses by to delegate the value of the State so you can now access parts as though it would be a List<Part>. This variable will now automatically update its value when anything changes in the Firestore, triggering a recomposition that updates your UI accordingly.
Using flows decouples reading values and changing values. If you change something you do not need to remember to update your UI anymore, that is now done automatically. This is a core feature of the Unidirectional Data Flow paradigm that is especially useful when working with Compose.

Thank you. Not only does that make a lot of sense, but it really helps me to code better.

The reason I used runblocking, is because I need the thread to pause in order to populate the value of partsList in the function that call getPartsList() (I have edited my original post to include this function). If I use viewModelScope.launch(), won't the thread throw an error since it will continue before the value partsList is retrieved? I also did not use Flows because I just want to get the latest partsList when the getOrderSummary function is called. This function is is used once per month to create a report. In my use case, is it still better to use flows?

If it should be displayed in the UI then I see no reason not to use a Flow. It elegantly solves a lot of issues you would otherwise need to handle some other way (like the need to wait for the function to return, which, in your case, would block the UI and make it unresponsive).

I see. Thanks again.
